# Accessing the stock quantity of an item on AliExpress in real-time

Tags: javascript, iframe, aliexpress

I'm not a web developer, hence I have to ask... 
Given the URL of a product detail page on AliExpress, without actually rendering the page, I want to extract the in-stock quantity of the item from the page.

A view-source of the page shows that the element is as follows...

```html
 <span class="p-available-stock" data-role="available-stock-tips">(<em data-role="stock-num" id="j-sell-stock-num"></em> <em data-role="available-copywriter"></em>)</span>
```

The value required to know the current stock status in real-time is in

```html
<em data-role="stock-num" id="j-sell-stock-num"> </em>
```

I suspect it can be done by javascript if the URL is referenced in an iframe.
We only want the stock status/qty, no need to render the contents of the iframe. 
Not found or zero should trigger an out of stock response, otherwise, we display the current quantity available.

I don't see why WooDropShip can't do this. Can you think of a reason why it can't be done in real-time instead of the daily updates they provide?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to load iframe url and search for given html element inside of its html code.